# Spring & Hibernate : Could not synchronize database state with session

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am getting following exception, kindly help me....

```
    (AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:324) - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.xxx.exx.rxx.entity.CallSignStatusEntity#21123]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1934)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2578)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2478)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2805)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1175)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1251)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:921)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
    at com.xxx.exx.rxx.dao.hibernate.CallxxxDaoImpl.getCallxxxStatusOfLoginOfficer(CallxxxDaoImpl.java:244)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy809.getCallSignStatusOfLoginOfficer(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxx.exx.rxx.business.impl.OfficerManagerImpl.getOfficerCallxxxBasic(OfficerManagerImpl.java:438)
    at com.xxx.exx.rxx.business.impl.OfficerManagerImpl.getUserCallxxxBasicInfo(OfficerManagerImpl.java:757)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy875.getUserCallxxxBasicInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxx.exx.ims.util.OperationsPlanUtil.getUserCallxxxName(OperationsPlanUtil.java:1203)
    at com.xxx.exx.ims.business.impl.IncidentFolderManagerImpl.createIncidentEventLogForCreateIncident(IncidentFolderManagerImpl.java:635)
    at com.xxx.exx.ims.business.impl.IncidentFolderManagerImpl.createIncidentEventLog(IncidentFolderManagerImpl.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
    at $Proxy870.createIncidentEventLog(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxx.exx.rxx.business.impl.EventLogManagerImpl.insertIncidentEventLog(EventLogManagerImpl.java:210)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy876.insertIncidentEventLog(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxx.exx.rxx.business.impl.CallxxxStatusManagerImpl.logIncidentResourceStatusUpdate(CallxxxxStatusManagerImpl.java:524)
    at com.xxx.exx.rxx.business.impl.CallxxxStatusManagerImpl.handleCallxxxStatus2Available(CallxxxxStatusManagerImpl.java:286)
    at com.xxx.exx.rxx.business.impl.CallxxxxStatusManagerImpl.updateCallxxxxToStatus(CallxxxxStatusManagerImpl.java:146)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most important stuff you need to look at in your stacktrace is

> org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)

This gives you enough indication what could be going wrong underneath. As mentioned in the trace you have two possibilities

1. The row you are trying to update was modified by some other source and the copy you have is not the updated one. So your changes were discarded and this exception was thrown. If this is the issue, you must start looking at locking mechanisms. By default hibernate uses optimistic locking.
2. Mapping corresponding to the object you are trying to save is incorrect.

My guess is, your application will have first issue but still you need to verify and find out the exact cause.

Hope that helps.